# Can an event based task in Codesys trigger on a falling edge?

Tags: codesys

I am currently working on a project that incorporates an EStop circuit. The EStop circuit transmits a 'normally on' (TRUE) signal under normal circumstances. When the EStop button is pressed the signal drops out and becomes FALSE. The digital signal is just for me to catch so I can potentially issue a 'one-shot' command (controlled stop), in the brief period, before connection to all motors and systems fault out.

I have tried configuring an event based task under 'Task Configurations' using the digital EStop output (seemed like the most ideal use case). However the 'event' conditions require a Boolean variable and will only trigger on a rising edge instance. Because my EStop signal is normally 'on' (TRUE) this will not work for me unless I can somehow invert the conditions of the event.
[image]

I understand I can incorporate the functionality I am looking for within my main task using an if statement and an inverter, but it seems silly there seems to be no option to invert the conditions of the event.

If what I am asking for is possible please let me know. If anyone can confirm it is NOT possible I will also accept that answer.

Comment: I have not used event-based tasks, so I cannot answer your specific question. But maybe you could have a separate variable that you (programmatically) set as the negation of your estop signal so that it produces the rising edge you (may) need?  Also, to you really expect your safety system will afford your enough time to do anything useful before motors stop? If you realistically cannot do anything quick enough, maybe you could do away with the added complexity in your project.

Comment: I could and I did think of that but I figured it wouldn't be much different than checking for the EStop in my main task... which I am currently doing and so far has worked as intended and still plenty fast. I will say my EStop circuit is designed with a short, but intentional, delay once it is pressed for the exact purpose of providing a short buffer so that I can safely reset or stop my system. About a second or two I think. For my application it just felt obvious to use the event driven task. However, this limitation feels like it should be avoidable without any extra level of complexity.

Comment: I assumed you had at most milliseconds to do anything. One or two seconds seems like plenty of time for someone to be hurt after the circuit is tripped, but I really do not know the application.  Personally, I prefer "coded" solution rather than things that depend on IDE configuration, but that is a matter of taste.